# rpython and imaplib sending a search query to imap

Tags: python, r, imap, imaplib

I'm trying to import an email with a particular search string from the server. I'm using the following code.

```
library(rPython)
python.exec("import imaplib
            import email")
python.exec('
            m=imaplib.IMAP4("imap.myserver.com","143")
            m.login(r"myid","mypass")
            m.select()')

python.exec('r,data=m.search(None,\'HEADER From "*cds*"\')')
a = python.get("data")
```

but it seems to not like the escaped apostrophes. I get the message

```
Error in python.exec("r,data=m.search(None,'HEADER From \"*cds*\"')") : 
  SEARCH command error: BAD ['unable to handle request: Invalid search parameters: "HEADER FROM \\"*CDS*\\""']
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this right? Thanks